# How to set start and end time for fullcalendar agendaWeek view?

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible to set a start and end time for the agendaWeek view in fullcalendar? I want to save the actual chosen week in a cookie and open this week when the user opens the calendar the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/

How did I do?

First of all - everything can be found in this amazing site.. the plugin actual manual.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/

Then you can use this

```
.fullCalendar( 'changeView', viewName )
```

Avaialble views

> month available since version 1.3
>
> basicDay - since version 1.3
>
> agendaWeek available since version 1.4
>
> agendaDay - since version 1.4

Apart from that - You can call the gotoDate from a cookie or other variable after the initialisation of the calendar

> gotoDate
>
> Moves the calendar to an arbitrary year/month/date.

```
 .fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', year [, month, [ date ]] ) IMPORTANT: month is 0-based, meaning January=0, February=1, etc.
```

and that should be called form an anonymous function - something in the line of

```
 $("#youCalendarID").fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', getCookie.year, getCookie.Month)
```

Ya MAN! Dont forget to look at this site
***http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/***

Comment: Sorry, but that was not the question. I know how to change the view and how to get the current view. I want to tell the calendar to open one view starting with a specific date, e.g. 1st April 2010. When I open a view the calendar always starts with the current date. That´s my problem.

Comment: ohhhh-- sorry- you two line description did not fully describe your problem. but you comment has cleared everything up now. Let me go and check the full calendar docuemntation for you and then rewrite it here

Comment: Sorry, you are right! So I set the cookies inside the viewDisplay function whenever I switch the week/month...?

Comment: Yes :) You can do it that way :) And then when the page reloads and there is a cookie set- then use that- or use a default.

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes the simple solutions are the best!